# Memory organization for OpenCL local memory on Nvidia GPUs

Tags: opencl, gpu, nvidia

I am trying to optimize my OpenCL kernel using local memory, specifically for use on Nvidia GPUs. I read about warps and how they can access local memory banks efficiently and how bank conflicts happen. One thing I could not find an example of is how this memory is allocated with multiple local memory declarations.

For example in this OpenCL kernel:

```
__kernel void computeExample(__global float* input,
                             __global float* output,
                             __local float* multiplier,
                             __local float* offsets)
{
    uint localId = get_local_id(0);

    multiplier[localId] = localId * 2.0f;
    offsets[localId] = localId + 2.0f;

    // compute something here
}
```

This is just for illustration, but what I want to know is when I declare two or more local memory variables, how are they organized in memory specifically on nvidia cards. Are they allocated end to end so as one begins at the end of the previous? Or does each local variable start at the first memory bank leaving possible padding between variables but start on a 128byte boundary (32 banks x 4 bytes per bank). Also does the order of declaration in the kernel determine which order they reside in memory?

What I want to is optimize my local memory size to avoid bank conflicts and take advantage as much possible coalesced accessing.

I understand this may vary from device to device and even possibly on different nvidia GPUs so there are no guarantees, but any ideas or tips on best way to organize the local data would be helpful information.

Thank you
Scott

Comment: try cuda, opencl seems like it may be more complicated than necessary

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately I am tied with OpenCL for reasons outside of my control.

Comment: It's no more complicated in OpenCL than CUDA. Shared local memory is small and resides with the SM while global memory is large and shared by all SMs. The main use of SLM to the cache global reads that are going to be used by multiple work items. If you're not doing that, you don't need to use SLM.